# Sentence vs sentence fragment

Tags: sentence

> Though, I like chocolates

> Though I like chocolates

Although the first one is a complete sentence, the second one is a sentence fragment, right? In the second expression, there is anticipation of more words to follow. In the first expression, there is no such anticipation.

Comment: Are you placing importance on the full stop?

Comment: Presumably there were words *before* the first sentence, so it isn't complete. On its own, 'though' is meaningless.

Comment: @BillJ No. I should have typesetted better. I removed both fullstops.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Most people in Sweden despise chocolates. Though, I like it a lot." It is a  full sentence here, right?

Comment: I was just saying: your second sentence needs more words (after) and the first needs more words (before). Neither is complete as they are, but "I like chocolates." is a full sentence.

Comment: You can't usually start a "single clause" utterance with ***though***. Normally the format is ***[al]though <clause #1>, <clause #2>*** as in *Although I like chocolate, they don't.* Without the second clause ***they don't** [like chocolate]*, there's no justification for starting the utterance with "contrastive " ***[al]though*** (because nothing is being contrasted, obviously).

Comment: ...but the definition of "a sentence" is flexible. Some peope in some contexts would say ***They don't*** isn't a sentence. Others would think different. But it certainly can't be a "standalone" utterance - if you walk up to someone out of the blue and say *"They don't"*, they won't have a clue what you mean.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I'm not sure what you're getting at here. Do you intend "though" to be concessive, or adverbial? Your first example suggests the latter. Without full stops, they can only be non-sentences (your 'fragments').

Comment: "I like chocolates, though" would work as a sentence, assuming you had just made a statement which could be taken to imply that you didn't - but not with _though_ placed first.

Comment: @KateBunting It's OK because that "though" is being used in the sense "however". It's not clear to me what the OP is driving at.

Comment: Are you trying to decide whether something someone actually says is "wrong" so that you can know you "shouldn't" write or say that?

Comment: I think it would be common to omit the comma after sentence-adverbial *though* in a short sentence (although a comma after subordinating-conjunction *though* is generally wrong *ceteris paribus*). I don't think you can tell what either string of words is doing in the examples in the question.

Comment: There is always such confusion between spoken English and written English and for the first **more context** is the only way to go.